# jquery get multidimensional array based on parent

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to create an ajax filter, in my backend I need seperated arrays for each filter. So I can run multiple whereins.
My HTML looks like:

```
<div class="products-filter-page">
    <input data-id="18" type="checkbox" value="" class="checkbox-filter-option">test
    <input data-id="19" type="checkbox" value="" class="checkbox-filter-option">test
    <input data-id="20" type="checkbox" value="" class="checkbox-filter-option">test
</div>

<div class="products-filter-page">
    <input data-id="21" type="checkbox" value="" class="checkbox-filter-option">test
    <input data-id="22" type="checkbox" value="" class="checkbox-filter-option">test
    <input data-id="22" type="checkbox" value="" class="checkbox-filter-option">test
</div>
```

Now when I select something I send all the slected data-id's in an ajax call. However I want them seperated based on theyr parent. For example i have filters with data-id 18,19 and 22

18,19 have the same parent so I have 1 array with [18,19] and one array with [22].

My current code gets everything needed except seperation based on parent.

```
 var filterProducts = function() {
   var selectedItems = [];
   $(".checkbox-filter-option:checked").each(function () {
     selectedItems.push($(this).data('id'));
   });
   console.log(selectedItems);
   if(selectedItems.length > 0){

     /*$.ajax({
           data : { ids:selectedItems
           //some calls
        });
     */
   }

 };

$( ".checkbox-filter-option" ).on( "click", filterProducts );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wot3o8a/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I made an example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/4wot3o8a/2/

```
var selectedItems = [[],[]];
$(".checkbox-filter-option:checked").each(function() {
  if ($(this).parent()[0] == $(".products-filter-page")[0] ) {
    selectedItems[0].push($(this).data('id'));
  } else {
    selectedItems[1].push($(this).data('id'));
  }
});
```

Hopefully this helps you achieve what you are trying for.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html part as `<input data-id="18" type="checkbox" value="" class="checkbox-filter-option" name=filter-X>`
For 1st groop filter-1 and nth group filter-2.

`Var filterVal = {};
    Each loop{
    Var Name =$(this).attr('nane')];
    If(!filterVal[Name])filterVal[Name]=[];
     filterVal[Name].push($(this).data('id'));
     }`